# Interface reference counting in Delphi Supports function

Tags: delphi, interface

I have class `THuman` which implements interface `ICanTalk`.

But whenever I try to check if human can talk, `Supports` function destroys  object instance, despite the reference in the code.

What did I misunderstood?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 Obj:TInterfacedObject;
begin
 Obj:=THuman.Create('Great guy');
 // if Supports(Obj, ICanTalk) then //Object destroyed here if uncommented
   (Obj as  ICanTalk).TalkTo(Memo1.Lines);
end;
```

Implementation

```
ICanTalk = interface
  ['{57E5EF90-EB11-421C-AAFB-18CD789C0956}']
    procedure TalkTo(List:TStrings);
  end;

THuman = class(TInterfacedObject, ICanTalk)
  private
    FName: string;
  public
    procedure TalkTo(List:TStrings);
    property Name:string read FName;
    constructor Create(const AName:string);
end;

constructor THuman.Create(const AName: string);
begin
 FName:=AName;
end;

procedure THuman.TalkTo(List: TStrings);
begin
 List.Add(Name+' says Hello World!');
end;
```

Comment: If you are already working with TInterfacedobject, you should consequently also work with the interface variable and not with the object variable.
```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 Obj: ICanTalk;
begin
 Obj:=THuman.Create('Great guy');
 if Supports(Obj, ICanTalk) then //Didn't destroy the object!
   obj.TalkTo(Memo1.Lines);
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected. When you read the documentation about the [`Supports`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.SysUtils.Supports) function, you found this:

> ## Warning
>
> With the exception of the overload that checks whether a TClass implements an interface, all the other versions of Supports will extract an interface reference either from an object or from another interface reference, causing the reference count of the underlying object to be incremented, and then will release the interface upon exit (decrementing the reference count). For objects that have a reference count of zero, this will result in the object destruction.
>
> ```pascal
> var 
>   Obj: TInterfacedObject;
> begin
>   Obj := TInterfacedObject.Create;
>   if Supports(Obj, IInterface) then { ... at this point Obj will be freed }
> end;
> ```

You wrote,

> despite the reference in the code(in visible area)

No, there is no reference. You declared `Obj` as `TInterfacedObject` (a class instance variable -- not an interface variable), and so there is no reference counting.

If you instead use an interface-typed variable, it will use reference counting:

```pascal
var
  Obj: IInterface;
```

Comment: What if i need to check a List<TComponent> if each item Supports for specified interface ?

Comment: @Valeriy.B you can call Supports safely on a TComponent as they do not descend from TInterfacedObject and do not implement their own reference counting.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior really annoyed me. Why did Embarcadero not declare the internal variable as **[unsafe]**. In the following example, the object is only released with FreeAndNil. Alternatively, you can use TInterfacedPersistent instead of TInterfacedObject. Then you always have to release the object yourself.

```
program Project3;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
ICanTalk = interface
  ['{57E5EF90-EB11-421C-AAFB-18CD789C0956}']
    procedure TalkTo;
  end;

  THuman = class(TInterfacedObject, ICanTalk)
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  private
    FName: string;
  public
    procedure TalkTo;
 end;

procedure THuman.TalkTo;
begin
end;

destructor THuman.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
end;

var
  o      : THuman;
  [unsafe]
  intf   : IInterface;

begin
  try
    o := THuman.Create;
    Supports(o, ICanTalk, intf);
    Intf := nil;   //Didn't call destructor cause of [unsafe]!
    FreeAndNil(o); //Call destructor!
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: The normal behavior of an interfaced object when assigning it to an interface, is to use reference counting. This is by design. The design choices can by argued, but this specific choice has never been a problem as I mainly use objects and free them and only use interfaced object with auto-ref-counting in mind…